# Print Label With Labelwriter 450 In Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel, printing

I want to print label in a Laravel view with data which is coming dynamically. I want to use LabelWriter 450 for this purpose

width: 89mm; height: 41mm;

How can i do that?

I tried the following code but it opens full page for printing, not according to size.

```
 <style>
        @media print {
            body * {
                visibility: hidden;
            }

            .label,
            .label * {
                visibility: visible;
            }

            .label {
                width: 89mm;
                height: 41mm;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="labelContent" class="label">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="printButton" onclick="printLabel()">Print</button>

        <h3>Order ID: {{ $repair->id }}</h3>
        <p>Client ID: {{ $repair->user->id }}</p>
        <p>Order Date: {{ $repair->created_at->format('Y-m-d') }}</p>
        <p>Fault: {{ $repair->selected_issues }}
        </p>
        <p>Pin/Password: {{ $repair->password }}</p>
        <p>Authorize For Reset: {{ !empty($repair->authorization) ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        function printLabel() {
            window.print();
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

What should i try now to print with specific width and height?